# Mouse pointer gets invisible after standby

Tags: mouse

My mouse pointer gets invisible after i start from standby. It works when i click on the applications (with feeling, i cant see it) but is not to see. I have Ubuntu-Studio 16.04.
What should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue. I did some research and found that if you hit 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>f1</kbd>, this puts you in a terminal. then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>f7</kbd> and this brings back the desktop with a functioning mouse cursor.

Comment: Yes i know that, thats what i am doing also. I wanted to know why this happens and how to fix the bug

Comment: I would suggest to check if it's a bug that is already reported on Launchpad.  If not, I would suggest that you try to report it yourself.

Comment: @SvetlanaBelkin How can i check if its reported? I haven't done something like this before.

Comment: @amirteymuri Just use the search bar from the homepage and use the terms of your question here along with Ubuntu Studio.  Or try to report the bug within the Ubuntu Studio package/project, but check if there is any like yours.