# help: invisible mouse pointer

Tags: unity, xorg, mouse, window-manager, mouse-pointer

After pressing `ctrl-alt-F1` to login to a virtual console I lose the mouse when going back to the GUI.  Logging out, which isn't easy without a visible mouse pointer, brings back the pointer.

How can I "refresh" the pointer from the GUI when it goes invisible?

There's no nvidia, and this only occurs after accessing the virtual consoles.

---

Might be a bug:

[Mouse pointer gets invisible after standby](https://askubuntu.com/q/808879/)

similar but different from:

https://askubuntu.com/q/736720/